# React native flatlist - error while rendering image from arrays

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Currently, I am a student and working on a personal project - building a newspaper reading application for Android. This is not my first project, and flatlist has always played an important role in my projects. But this time, for some reason, a hidden error appeared. The image appears altered as shown in the image below.

It will return to normal if I interact with the flatlist like pressing another item or scrolling the flatlist or else the image will be stucked at the weird stage.

At first, I thought it was because I used both scroll view and flatlist in the same view.

I tried commenting out the scrollview part, but it only helps render images of directly visible elements. As for the elements that are rendered after I scroll the flatlist, the image will still be distorted for a short time before it is corrected and displays the correct image provided.

At this point, I thought it might be because I passed too much nested data and tried deleting some of its, but the image rendering error still appeared whether I used or not used the scrollview and flatlist at the same time.

I can no longer think why this situation occurs because in the terminal, it does not display any warnings that I can follow. I wonder if anyone has encountered this type of bug? And can everyone share with me the solutions? Thank you.

This is the weird stage when am redering the image in flat list

[image: The image was when am using both scrollview and flatlist at the same time, if i deleted the scrollview and only using flatist the second image will be normal but the bug will still apparent in the following items]

In the Homae tab that i made, i used 2 custom components i made before hand to display the new:

This is the action bar - using to interact with user, help them like, comment and share and also show the new's popularity like the amount of comment and view the new has.

```
    import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native';
    import React from 'react';
    import {components, fonts} from '../Styles';
    import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

    type Prop = {
       commentCount?: number;
       viewCount?: number;
       likePress?: () => void;
       commentPress?: () => void;
       sharePress?: () => void;
       like?: boolean;
     };

     const ActionBar = (props: Prop) => {
        return (
         <View
           style={[
             components.rowSpaceBetween,
             {
               alignItems: 'center',
               paddingLeft: 15,
          marginTop: 15,
        },
      ]}>

      {/* Like cmt share */}
      <View
        style={[
          components.rowSpaceBetween,
          {alignItems: 'center', width: '30%'},
        ]}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props?.likePress && props.likePress()}>
          <Image
            source={
              props?.like
                ? require('../../../assets/images/icons/heart_fill.png')
                : require('../../../assets/images/icons/heart_line.png')
            }
            style={{tintColor: Colors.primary}}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => props?.commentPress && props.commentPress()}>
          <Image
            source={require('../../../assets/images/icons/comment_line.png')}
            style={{tintColor: Colors.primary}}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => props?.sharePress && props.sharePress()}>
          <Image
            source={require('../../../assets/images/icons/share_line.png')}
            style={{tintColor: Colors.primary}}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      {/* News' cmt and view quantity*/}
      <View
        style={[
          components.rowSpaceEvently,
          {alignItems: 'center', width: '35%'},
        ]}>
        <Text style={[fonts.tag, {color: Colors.accent}]}>{props?.commentCount || "4.5k"}</Text>

        <Image
          source={require('../../../assets/images/icons/fire_fill.png')}
          style={{width: 15, height: 15, tintColor: Colors.accent}}
        />

        <View style={[components.dot, {marginHorizontal: 5}]} />

        <Text style={[fonts.tag, {color: Colors.accent}]}>{props?.commentCount || "200k"}</Text>

        <Image
          source={require('../../../assets/images/icons/eye_fill.png')}
          style={{width: 15, height: 15, tintColor: Colors.accent}}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
    );
    };

    export default ActionBar;
```

I used the action bar inside the card big which i used for displaying the new in home tab

```
    import {
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ColorValue,
    ViewStyle,
    }   from 'react-native';
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import {Colors, components, fonts} from '../Styles';
    import ActionBar from '../bars/ActionBar';

    type Props = {
    title?: string;
    description?: string;
    tag?: string;
    cover?: any;
    style? : ViewStyle | ViewStyle[];
    onPress?: () => void;
    commentCount?: number;
    viewCount?: number;
    like?: boolean;
    };

    const Big = (props: Props) => {
    const title = 'The Florida Governor debate hits the fan';
    const description =
    'ST. PETERSBURG, Fla. — The Florida governor’s race was spinning ' +
    'wildly on Thursday, almost as fast as that electric fan former Gov. Charlie Crist ' +
    'insists on bringing along to campaign appearances.';

    return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={[components.cardBig_Container, props?.style]}>
      <View>
        {/* cover */}
        <Image
          source={
            props?.cover ||
            require('../../../assets/images/contents/CNNnews.jpeg')
          }
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: 200,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
            borderTopRightRadius: 20,
          }}
        />

        {/* title */}
        <View
          style={[
            components.rowSpaceBetween,
            {
              marginVertical: 5,
            },
          ]}>
          <Text
            style={[
              fonts.title,
              {
                width: '80%',
                paddingLeft: 10,
              },
            ]}>
            {props?.title || title}
          </Text>

          {/* Tag */}
          <View
            style={[
              components.rowSpaceBetween,
              {justifyContent: 'flex-start', minWidth: 55},
            ]}>
            <Image
              source={require('../../../assets/images/icons/tag.png')}
              style={{width: 15, height: 15, tintColor: Colors.accent}}
            />

            <Text style={[fonts.tag, {color: Colors.accent, paddingLeft: 5}]}>
              {props?.tag || 'Tag'}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        {/* description */}
        <Text
          numberOfLines={2}
          style={[
            {
              width: '90%',
              paddingLeft: 15,
              paddingRight: 5,
            },
          ]}>
          {props?.description || description}
        </Text>

        {/* action bar */}
        <ActionBar
          commentCount={props?.commentCount}
          viewCount={props.viewCount}
          likePress={() => props?.onPress && props.onPress()}
          commentPress={() => props?.onPress && props.onPress()}
          sharePress={() => props?.onPress && props.onPress()}
          like={props?.like}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    );
    };

    export default Big;
```

This is the home tab that i create, as you can see it have a scrollview to generate the tag and flatlist to display the new

```
    import {
    View,
    Text,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    StatusBar,
    FlatList,
    } from 'react-native';
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import {Colors, components, fonts, styles} from '../../customs/Styles';
    import HeaderBar from '../../customs/bars/HeaderBar';
    import Big from '../../customs/cards/Big';

    type News = {
    title?: string;
    description?: string;
    tag?: string;
    cover?: any;
    commentCount?: number;
    viewCount?: number;
    like?: boolean;
    };

    type Props = {
    news?: News[];
    };

    const Home = (prop : Props) => {
    const tag: String[] = [
    'Công nghệ - Kỹ thuật',
    'Lập trình',
    'Phần mềm',
    'Mạng máy tính',
    'An ninh mạng',
    'Trí tuệ nhân tạo',
    'Đám Mây',
    'Hệ điều hành',
    'Thiết bị di động',
    'Website',
    // Thêm các tag khác tùy ý
    ];

    const news : News[] = prop.news || [
    {
      title: 'The Florida Governor debate hits the fan',
      description: 'This is the description',
      tag: 'Công nghệ - Kỹ thuật',
      cover: require('../../../assets/images/contents/CNNnews.jpeg'),
      commentCount: 100,
      viewCount: 1000,
      like: true,
    },
    {
      title: 'The Florida Governor debate hits the fan',
      description: 'This is the description',
      tag: 'Công nghệ - Kỹ thuật',
      cover: require('../../../assets/images/contents/CNNnews.jpeg'),
      commentCount: 100,
      viewCount: 1000,
      like: true,
    },
    {
      title: 'The Florida Governor debate hits the fan',
      description: 'This is the description',
      tag: 'Công nghệ - Kỹ thuật',
      cover: require('../../../assets/images/contents/CNNnews.jpeg'),
      commentCount: 100,
      viewCount: 1000,
      like: true,
    },
    {
      title: 'The Florida Governor debate hits the fan',
      description: 'This is the description',
      tag: 'Công nghệ - Kỹ thuật',
      cover: require('../../../assets/images/contents/CNNnews.jpeg'),
      commentCount: 100,
      viewCount: 1000,
      like: true,
    },
    {
      title: 'The Florida Governor debate hits the fan',
      description: 'This is the description',
      tag: 'Công nghệ - Kỹ thuật',
      cover: require('../../../assets/images/contents/CNNnews.jpeg'),
      commentCount: 100,
      viewCount: 1000,
      like: true,
    },
    {
      title: 'The Florida Governor debate hits the fan',
      description: 'This is the description',
      tag: 'Công nghệ - Kỹ thuật',
      cover: require('../../../assets/images/contents/CNNnews.jpeg'),
      commentCount: 100,
      viewCount: 1000,
      like: true,
    }
    ];


    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(tag[0]);

    return (
    <View style={[styles.container2]}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor={Colors.background} barStyle="dark-content" />

      <HeaderBar
        style={{
          marginVertical: 10,
        }}
      />

      <ScrollView
        style={[components.tag_Container]}
        horizontal = {true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
        {tag.map((item, index) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            activeOpacity={0.5}
            onPress={() => setSelected(item)}>
            <Text
              style={[
                selected == item ? fonts.link : fonts.tag,
                {
                  marginRight: 15,
                  color: selected == item ? Colors.black : undefined,
                  borderBottomColor: Colors.primary,
                  borderBottomWidth: selected == item ? 2 : 0,
                  paddingBottom: 5,
                },
              ]}>
              {item}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>

      <FlatList
      data={news}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
        <View
          style={{
            height: 20,
          }}/>
      )}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <Big {...item} />
      )}
      >

      </FlatList>
    </View>
    );
    };

    export default Home;
```

Comment: have you tried using another image component like [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) to rule out the issue being an Image component issue?

Comment: @Oluwajuwon Well no, this is first time i am facing this error so i don't really know what should i do to get rid of it plus i want to understand why, how and what cause the error too. But thank you for the recommendation